# Ruby - Use Regex to find city name in string

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to use regex to pull city names from an array of strings. Here's how the strings are formatted:

```
City of Covina Police Department, Covina, CA 91728
```

Right now I'm pulling state abbreviations by looping through each string, then looping through an array of US state abbreviations to see if the string includes one of them, like so:

```
states = [my array of states]
string = the current string from the array
states.each do |state|
    if string.include?(state)
        counter[state] += 1
    end
end
```

Based on how the strings are formatted, how would I use Regex to find the city in each string? I'm thinking that because I've found the state, and because the city is always immediately preceding the state, I should be able to use this to find it, but I'm not that well versed in Regex so I'm having trouble with the answer. Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming that a regex is required makes this what is referred to as an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There may be non-regex solutions, so just say you want to extract the city names.

Comment: Of crucial importance is the line format. You said "Here's how the strings are formatted". If all of the strings have two commas per line, with the city name and nothing else between (or if the last two commas in the line surround the city name), the solution is easy, so you should state whether that's the case. If it isn't, you need to be precise in describing the possible variations in line format. Please elaborate by editing, rather than trying to explain in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If:

- city names are always bracketed by commas and
- the comma following the city name is the last comma in the line

then you can write:

```
str.split(',')[-2].strip
```

Examples:

```
str = "City of Covina Police Department, Covina, CA 91728"
str.split(',')[-2].strip #=> "Covina" 

str = "City of Covina, Police Department, Covina, CA 91728"
str.split(',')[-2].strip #=> "Covina"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not from US so I have no idea wether the state code is always in format XX and zip code alway 5 digits, but based on that assumption. here it is

```
/\w+(?=, \w{2} \d{5}$)/
```

`(?=...$)` is positive lookahead for the end of the string

`\w{2}` state code

`\d{5}` zip code

Comment: I don't live in the US either, but I think the zip codes can be `98230` or `98230-1234`, so you might want to add `(?:-\d{4})?`. Also, the state abbreviations are always two uppercase letters, so maybe `[A-Z]{2}`.